# Where are the global settings stored for a given sound card (volume, balance, volume step)?

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

Context:

I have this Asus Xonar U3 USB sound card. When initially installed it worked perfectly. At some point I've unplugged and then plugged it again to the laptop while it was working (Ubuntu 16.04). From that point on volume became too loud and the sound was muted prematurely when volume slider was about 25% (i.e. not 0). A solution is described [here](https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/) but on 16.04 it causes another problems (but that is not important now).

After some experiments I found that the problem with the volume is starting to appear only if you unplug and then plug the USB card while PC is working, i.e. it seems that Ubuntu is messing up by adding up the volume step to sound card settings (or something like that).

Where are the sound card global settings stored so I can check if that is the case? By global I mean NOT the ~/.config/pulse. Is there such file?